# Continuity of a function $ f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\backslash\left(0,0\right)\to\biggl[0,2\pi\biggr) $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Having $f$ calculate the counter-clockwise angle between a vector $ \vec{v} $ and the vector $(1,0) $

I will use $ \vec{v}=(x,y) $
So Using the scalar product I find that: $$ \vec{v}\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0
\end{array}\right)=x=\left|\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right|\cos\alpha\Rightarrow\cos\alpha=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\Rightarrow\alpha=\arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\right) $$

I know that if $ \lVert V-A\rVert=\sqrt{\left(x-a_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(y-a_{2}\right)^{2}}<\delta $ and if it leads to $ \lVert F\left(v\right)-F\left(a\right)\rVert<\varepsilon $ then it is continuous at point $A $

I understand I need to do something of the sort $$ \lVert F\left(v\right)-F\left(a\right)\rVert=\left|\arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\right)-\arccos\left(\frac{a_{1}}{\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}+a_{2}^{2}}}\right)\right|<\text{better expresion with delta}<\varepsilon $$
But what upper bound can I use? I thought about Taylor expansion of \arccos but even that probably wont get me to where I need.

Any hints?

Comment: I have a feeling your function is not continuous (it looks like the archetypal example when looking at a determination of the argument/logarithm). Hint: what is the value of f at (1,0)? And what happens when a vector approches (1,0) but from below? Say, (1,-x) with small x>0.

Comment: $$\biggl[{\rm Why?}\biggr)$$

Comment: So I drew the 3 cases on paper (v is the same as $(1,0)$,v is $(1,\varepsilon) $and v is $(1,-\varepsilon) $
I assume that because $ 2\pi $ isn't in the range, the angle between $ (1,0) and (1,0) $ is actually 0.
So I have a big jump between $ 0 $ straight into almost $ 2\pi $, disproving continuity?

Comment: Yes, that's it!